# how to show text and images in one line in react native using react native render html?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

[image]

i want to show images and text in one line but it is not working how to do it. all content comes in one html string from backend.i m using react native render html for this to render text like this.

string is like this from backend. -> "`<p>Testing long messages with Text<img width="25" height="25" src="https://node.whizbite.com/media/emoji/png/emoji-32.png" +="" class="emojiHeight24 margin_right3"><img width="25" height="25" src="https://node.whizbite.com/media/emoji/png/emoji-31.png" +="" class="emojiHeight24 margin_right3"><img width="25" height="25" src="https://node.whizbite.com/media/emoji/png/emoji-30.png" +="" class="emojiHeight24 margin_right3">`"

```
                          <HTML
                              baseFontStyle={{
                                color: '#555555', 
                                fontSize: moderateScale(15),
                                fontWeight: '400', 
                                textAlign: 'left',
                              }}

                              containerStyle={{
                                marginLeft: 0,
                                marginRight: 10,
                                color:'#555555',
                                fontWeight: '400', 
                                textAlign: 'left',
                                flexDirection:'row',
                                paddingEnd: 10,
                              }}
                              html={item.message}
                             />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a style using `tagsStyles` and `classesStyles` props for each html tags or classes. The following code is an example of using this props:

```js
<HTML
   html={item.message}
   tagsStyles={{
      p: {
          fontSize: 22,
          lineHeight: 30,
          marginBottom: 0
      },
      img: {
          ...
      }
   }}
   classesStyles={{
      'custom-image': { 
           ... 
      } 
   }}
   ignoredStyles={['line-height']} />
```

Answer (score 0):

with `tagsStyles` prop you can do that

[image]

here is a code example

```
<HTML
html={item.message}
tagsStyles={{
          img: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
          },
          p: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
          },
        }}
/>
```

[here](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html#styling) is explaination

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Man.your answer is worked perfectly.Thnks for this solution.